# Self-induction in a circular coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

There's a formula for self inductance: $$ L=\frac{n\Phi}{i}$$ where n is the number of loops.

But the book also says self inductance is directly proportional to $ n^2 $

I totally agree with the second sentence. But the formula seems to show $L$ is directly proprtional to $n $ and not $ n^2 $.

I am confused. Can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice, the magnetic magnetic field $B$ at the center of  a coil carrying current $i$, with radius $r$ & having $n$ no. of turns  $$B=\frac{\mu_0}{2}\frac{ni}{r}$$
hence, magnetic flux $\phi$ linked to the coil is given as $$\Phi=BA=\frac{\mu_0}{2}\frac{ni}{r}\pi r^2=\frac{\mu_0 \pi nir}{2}$$ 
Now, setting the value of $\phi$, we get 
$$L=\frac{n\Phi}{i}=\frac{n\frac{\mu_0 \pi nir}{2}}{i}=\frac{\mu_0 \pi  n^2r}{2}$$
$$L\propto n^2$$
It is obvious that keeping other parameters constant, the self inductance $\color{red}{L}$ of a coil is directly proportional to $\color{red}{n^2}$

Comment: Oh, forgot to see the n hiding inside flux... thanks

Comment: You're also in the Physics community... congratulations on your astuteness.

Answer (score 0):

From your question,

Self inductance $L$ :
$$L=\frac{n\phi}{i}$$
Magnetic flux, is the product of Magnetic field and the area of cross section intercepted by magnetic field lines $$\phi=BA$$

Magnetic field is directly proportional to the number of turns in the inductor $$B\propto n$$

$$\phi\propto n$$
$$L\propto n\cdot n$$
$$\therefore L\propto n^2$$
I hope it helps you